# How to Fix : Non-nullable instance field 'userFuture' must be initialized?

Tags: flutter

> This is my code for main.dart :

```
 class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
Future userFuture; //error is here

  Future<List<String>> getData() async {
    var databaseRef2 = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
    databaseRef2 = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("Sliders");
    DatabaseEvent event = await databaseRef2.once();
    Map<dynamic, dynamic> values =
        event.snapshot.value as Map<dynamic, dynamic>;
    values.forEach((key, values) {
      imgList.add(values["img"]);
    });
    return imgList;
  }

  }
}
```

> If I declare Future as:

```
Future userFuture;
```

> I get this error :

```
Non-nullable instance field 'userFuture' must be initialized.
Try adding an initializer expression, or a generative constructor that initializes it
```

> Please tell me how to fix it ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

As per flutter [null-safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety) try to add ?

```
 Future? userFuture;
```

Or

```
late Future  userFuture;
```

Answer (score 1):

Well from sdk 2.12 onwards, dart supports null-safety
there are two ways to fix this error, since you haven't mentioned the use of userFuture.

1. add late keyboard before the initialisation `late Future userFuture`
2. add null safety operator `Future? userFuture`